# CompareTo methods from comparable with list

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I've written the answer to this question but on Netbeans it shows an error at this line:

```
        if (key.compareTo(obj) <= 1)
```

**The question is:**
Write a static method which takes a List or Set of objects which have a natural order, an object
of the base type of the List or Set, and an integer n, and returns true if at least n objects in the
List or Set are greater than the object argument according to their natural order, false
otherwise.

**My attempt:**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean question9(List<T> list, List obj, int n) {

            int count = 0;
            for (T key : list) {
                if (key.compareTo(obj) <= 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (n > count) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "shows an Error". Can you be a bit more specific? also, re-write this: if (n > count) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            } as return n <= count;
much easier to read

Comment: Why is it `List obj`? Also, `key.compareTo(obj) <= 1` is never the right check.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment says (emphasis mine):

> Write a static method which takes a List or Set of objects which have a natural order, **an object of the base type of the List or Set**

This does not mean that `obj` is a `List` or `Set`! This means that `obj` must be a `T`.

Also, your test is not good. The `Comparable` contract says that for two objects `x` and `y`, `x` is considered greater than `y` if `x.compareTo(y)` is greater than 0.

Therefore change your test to:

```
if (key.compareTo(obj) > 0)
```

Also, your final test can be simplified to:

```
return count >= n;
```

and you can even shortcut:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean question9(
    final Collection<T> collection, // assignment says List or Set
    final T obj, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (final T element: collection) {
        if (element.compareTo(obj) <= 0)
            continue;
        if (++count >= n)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh that makes sense...because the obj would also need to be generic because if List was an Integer then the obj should also be an Integer..I think! Thanks will mark correct once timer expires

Comment: There's another problem, and that's with your test. See updated answer.